# Determining PostgreSQL's port

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, port, ubuntu-9.10

I know that by default PostgreSQL listens on port 5432, but what is the command to actually determine PostgreSQL's port?

**Configuration:** Ubuntu 9.10 with PostgreSQL 8.4

Answer (score 41, accepted):

lsof and nmap are solutions, but they're not installed by default. What you want is netstat(8).

```
sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
```

And if you don't have netstat, but have ss

```
sudo ss -pln |grep postgres
```

Comment: Linux is supposedly migrating away from route/ifconfig/netstat. The equivalent modern command is `ss -plung|grep postgres` (note, same flags)

Comment: There is no `g` flag anymore for the `ss` command. Try: `ss -pa |grep postgresql`

Comment: @GrayedFox thanks for the update, but for me that gives the name of the port, not the number, so I think `ss -pan |grep postgres` is more suitable

Comment: `netstat` is not installed by default nowadays

Comment: @Flimm indeed, the other comments point to `ss`

Answer (score 15):

The PostgreSQL utility pg_lsclusters shows information about the configuration and status of all clusters, including the port number.

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Version Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory                     Log file
8.4     main      5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main       /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log
```

This also has the advantage of not requiring 'sudo' privileges to run.

On Debian and Ubuntu systems, the pg_lsclusters command is provided by the package postgresql-common, which should be installed by default with the postgresql server.

Comment: Note that `pg_lsclusters` is an Ubuntu-ism, and is *not* a standard Postgres command. It will work for this case, but is not a general-purpose solution...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it from inside the database, just do "SHOW port". But that assumes you've been able to connect to it, at least locally...

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching on the local machine, I would use the lsof command to check for the port postgresql is using

```
lsof -p <postgres_process_id>
```

Comment: You may have to run this as root.

Answer (score 2):

I have machines with multiple postgres instances running -- and so I also have the issue of trying to match up the correct database with each port.  I tend to do:

```
$ ps aux | grep  postgres | grep -v 'postgres:'
```

And then, for each of instances returned look for the directory (`-D` argument) and:

```
$ sudo grep port $DIR/postgresql.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution that I've found:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
sudo nmap localhost | grep postgresql
```

If you're wanting to search a non-local machine, just change `localhost` to the server's IP address.